# Show link only in JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON string -

```
{  
   "fruits":[  
      {  
         "name":"apples",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {  
         "name":"bananas",
         "id":"2"
      },
      {  
         "name":"oranges",
         "id":"3"
      },
      {  
         "name":"pears",
         "id":"4"
      },
      {  
         "name":"grapes",
         "id":"5"
      },
      {  
         "name":"strawberries",
         "id":"6"
      }
   ],
   "links":[  
      {  
         "source":"1",
         "target":"2"
      },
      {  
         "source":"1",
         "target":"3"
      },
      {  
         "source":"1",
         "target":"5"
      },
      {  
         "source":"4",
         "target":"5"
      },
      {  
         "source":"4",
         "target":"6"
      }
   ]
}
```

My question being is there a means to run the string through an algorithm that will only show the nodes and the links that are joined. So in the example the JSON should be (after removal of redundant data) -

```
{  
   "fruits":[  
      {  
         "name":"apples",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {  
         "name":"pears",
         "id":"4"
      },
      {  
         "name":"grapes",
         "id":"5"
      }
   ],
   "links":[  
      {  
         "source":"1",
         "target":"5"
      },
      {  
         "source":"4",
         "target":"5"
      }
   ]
}
```

As grapes are linked to both apples and pears. I have created an algorithm to remove any duplicates which works a treat however cannot crack one to show the linking entries.

I have iterated over all the **target** values

```
var lookup = {};
                var result = [];
                var links = jsonString['links'];
                for (var item, i = 0; item = links[i++];) {
                    var name = item.target;

                    if (!(name in lookup)) {
                        lookup[name] = 1;

                        // remove unique values to leave only multiple occurances 
                        // then based on the source and target values removes none related from fruits and rebuild JSON

                    }
                }
```

Comment: My attempted algorithm checked each fruit id and if there was only one reference of its id in the links (i.e.) not connecting 2 fruits then delete it, However was not working, I can post incomplete code if required.

Comment: @Dhiraj Bodicherla I have added my loop with explanation of how I believe it can be achieved however still at a loss.

Comment: I don't completely understand how the links work. Can you please explain more. Out of the links 1,2 1,3 1,5 how and why did you eliminate 1,2 and 1,3

Comment: So the resulting json should only have reference in the links where the target exists more than once, i.e. it is connected to more than one source. So in the above example, target with id 5 (grapes) is linked to both sources 1 and 4 (apples and pears). So both fruits and links have to have any other references removed where there is no link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is

1. Sort the links array (for efficiency)
2. Iterate through the links and search if adjacent items have same target

   1. If they do, then iterate through all the ones that have same target and push the links to linksArray and fruits to fruitsArray.
   2. If they do not, just iterate till the end and exit

In order to fetch the fruit iterate through data.fruits array and get the fruit based on the source and target ID

It would look something like this

```
function getLinkedFruits(data){

  var sortedLinks = data.links.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.target-b.target;
  });

  data.links = sortedLinks;

  var resultLinks = [], resultFruits = [];

  for(var i=0;i<data.links.length-1;i++){ 
    if(data.links[i].target === data.links[i+1].target){

      var j = i;

      var fruit1 = getFruitsBasedOnID(data.links[i].source);
      var fruit2 = getFruitsBasedOnID(data.links[i].target);

      if(resultFruits.indexOf(fruit1) == -1)
        resultFruits.push(fruit1);

      if(resultFruits.indexOf(fruit2) == -1)
        resultFruits.push(fruit2);

      while(data.links[j].target == data.links[i].target){
        resultLinks.push(data.links[j]);
        var fruit3 = getFruitsBasedOnID(data.links[j].source);
        if(resultFruits.indexOf(fruit3) == -1)
          resultFruits.push(fruit3);
        j++;
      }

      i=j-1;

    }
  }

  function getFruitsBasedOnID(ID){
    for(var i=0;i<data.fruits.length;i++){
      if(data.fruits[i].id == ID)
        return data.fruits[i];
    }
  }

  data.links = resultLinks;
  data.fruits = resultFruits;

  return data;

}

console.log(getLinkedFruits(data));
```

```js
var data = {
  "fruits": [{
    "name": "apples",
    "id": "1"
  }, {
    "name": "bananas",
    "id": "2"
  }, {
    "name": "oranges",
    "id": "3"
  }, {
    "name": "pears",
    "id": "4"
  }, {
    "name": "grapes",
    "id": "5"
  }, {
    "name": "strawberries",
    "id": "6"
  }],
  "links": [{
    "source": "1",
    "target": "2"
  }, {
    "source": "3",
    "target": "5"
  }, {
    "source": "1",
    "target": "3"
  }, {
    "source": "5",
    "target": "3"
  }, {
    "source": "1",
    "target": "5"
  }, {
    "source": "4",
    "target": "5"
  }, {
    "source": "4",
    "target": "6"
  }]
};

function getLinkedFruits(data) {

  var sortedLinks = data.links.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.target - b.target;
  });
  data.links = sortedLinks;
  var resultLinks = [],
    resultFruits = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.links.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data.links[i].target === data.links[i + 1].target) {
      var j = i;
      var fruit1 = getFruitsBasedOnID(data.links[i].source);
      var fruit2 = getFruitsBasedOnID(data.links[i].target);
      if (resultFruits.indexOf(fruit1) == -1)
        resultFruits.push(fruit1);
      if (resultFruits.indexOf(fruit2) == -1)
        resultFruits.push(fruit2);
      while (data.links[j].target == data.links[i].target) {
        resultLinks.push(data.links[j]);
        var fruit3 = getFruitsBasedOnID(data.links[j].source);
        if (resultFruits.indexOf(fruit3) == -1)
          resultFruits.push(fruit3);
        j++;
      }
      i = j - 1;
    }
  }

  function getFruitsBasedOnID(ID) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.fruits.length; i++) {
      if (data.fruits[i].id == ID)
        return data.fruits[i];
    }
  }

  data.links = resultLinks;
  data.fruits = resultFruits;

  return data;

}

console.log(getLinkedFruits(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution out:

```
function onlyLinked(input) {
    var fruitLinkCount = {}
    var fruitRequired = {}

    input.fruits.forEach(function(f) {
        fruitLinkCount[f.id] = 0
        fruitRequired[f.id] = false
    })

    input.links.forEach(function (l) {
        fruitLinkCount[l.target]++
    })

    var output = {}

    output.links = []

    input.links.forEach(function(l) {
        if (fruitLinkCount[l.target] > 1) {
            output.links.push(l)
            fruitRequired[l.source] = true
            fruitRequired[l.target] = true
        }
    })

    output.fruits = input.fruits.filter(function(f) {
        return fruitRequired[f.id]
    })

    return output

}
```

Comment: your algorithm breaks if there are more than two objects with same target. Like this http://jsbin.com/dejuse/edit?js,output The output links should be  `1-5, 2-5, 4-5`

Comment: why? why shouldn't 1-2 be in the links?

Comment: in the comments OP says *target exists more than once*. `1-2` should not be in the result because 2 is not connected to more than one sources. It would be in the result if there was another link say `4-2` (for e.g.)

Comment: ooohhh, got it now, i thought the edges were symmetrical

Comment: i've edited now to reflect the "only keeps links pointing to fruit that was pointed to more than once, and the fruits in those kept links" behaviour